# Error on deploying django app to Heroku -- TypeError: argument of type 'PosixPath' is not iterable

Tags: python, django, heroku

This is my first django project and I get this error when trying to deploy. It would be really appreciated if someone could help me with this.
TypeError: argument of type 'PosixPath' is not iterable
Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.

```
$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
remote:        122 static files copied to '/tmp/build_92e98a8b/staticfiles'.
remote:        Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:          File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
remote:            main()
remote:          File "manage.py", line 18, in main
remote:            execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
remote:            utility.execute()
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
remote:            self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 329, in run_from_argv
remote:            connections.close_all()
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 225, in close_all
remote:            connection.close()
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 190, in close
remote:            if not self.is_in_memory_db():
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 280, in is_in_memory_db
remote:            return self.creation.is_in_memory_db(self.settings_dict['NAME'])
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/creation.py", line 12, in is_in_memory_db
remote:            return database_name == ':memory:' or 'mode=memory' in database_name
remote:        TypeError: argument of type 'PosixPath' is not iterable
remote:
remote:  !     Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
remote:        See traceback above for details.
remote:
remote:        You may need to update application code to resolve this error.
remote:        Or, you can disable collectstatic for this application:
remote:
remote:           $ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
remote:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
```

This is my settings.py. I had a static error previously and then I added the static root. When I run the server locally the app works fine.

```
import os
from pathlib import Path        
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'blog.apps.BlogConfig',
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
    'crispy_forms',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

]
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'django_trial.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'django_trial.wsgi.application'
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT =   os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'blog-home'

LOGIN_URL = 'login'

EMAIL_BACKEND ='django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST ='smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ.get('User')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('AppPass')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes thats an issue many people face. To solve it, type this in the git bash cli,

`heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1` and again push your site to heroku

Comment: Hey, it worked fine. Thanks for the tip. But, what difference had been made and why is this error popping up?

Comment: It is used to stop django from collecting static files .While pushing our project, django must know the configuration of our static files before an upload.